# Best way to make a custom smooth scroll and scrollto coexist (ReactJs - Framer motion)

Tags: reactjs, smooth-scrolling, framer-motion

Made a smoothscroll component using framer motion that's working well :

```
export default function SmoothScroll({ children }: Props) {
  const { width } = useWindowSize();
  const scrollContainer = useRef() as RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
  const [pageHeight, setPageHeight] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // added a setTimeout so the page has the time to load and it still fits
      const scrollContainerSize =
        scrollContainer.current?.getBoundingClientRect();

      scrollContainerSize && setPageHeight(scrollContainerSize.height);
    }, 500);
  }, [width]);

  const { scrollY } = useScroll(); // measures how many pixels user has scrolled vertically
  // as scrollY changes between 0px and the scrollable height, create a negative scroll value...
  // ... based on current scroll position to translateY
  const transform = useTransform(scrollY, [0, pageHeight], [0, -pageHeight]);
  const physics = { damping: 15, mass: 0.17, stiffness: 55 }; // easing of smooth scroll
  const spring = useSpring(transform, physics); // apply easing to the negative scroll value

  return (
    <>
      <motion.div
        ref={scrollContainer}
        style={{ y: spring }} // translateY of scroll container using negative scroll value
        className="app fixed overflow-hidden w-screen"
      >
        {children}
      </motion.div>
      <motion.div style={{ height: pageHeight }} />
    </>
  );
}
```

The thing is, I'd like to scrollTo sections of my page upon click on the navbar but don't really know how to implement it without removing the smoothScroll ...
Tried the following logic but obviously it did not work as the vanilla scroll has been hijacked :

```
  const scrollToSection = (
    e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLLIElement, globalThis.MouseEvent>,
    anchor?: string
  ) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!anchor) return;
    const section = document.querySelector(anchor);
    section?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  };
```

Is it doable ?